# react set value to a textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, material-ui

everytime the closeEmail is triggered or called I wanted to assign the email.emailAddress as the value of the textfield.

just really new to react , what is the syntax or way to do this ?

Any idea guys ?

#code snippet

```
<div style={{ display: "block" }}>
                <FormControl sx={{ mt: 2, minWidth: 720 }}>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      display: "flex",
                      justifyContent: "space-between",
                      alignItems: "center",
                    }}
                  >
                    <TextField
                      style={{ width: "95%" }}
                      onChange={emailOnChange}
                      label="Email Address"
                      variant="filled"
                      name={email.emailAddress}
                      defaultValue={email.emailAddress}

                    />
                    <DeleteIcon style={{ color: "red" }} onClick={() => deleteEmail(email, prop.id)} />
                  </div>
```

#ts

```
 const closeEmail = (email: IEmail) => {
    const test = email.emailAddress;
    setOpenEmail(false);
    return email.emailAddress;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have to create the state for the TextField to set the value
you can achieve with the following changes

import at the top:-

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
```

then create state :-

```
const[emailValue, setEmailValue] = useState('');
```

on your function call closeEmail()

```
const closeEmail = (email: IEmail)=>{
count test = email.emailAddress;
//add
console.log("test",test);
setOpenEmail(false);
return email.emailAddress;
}
```

Add console to check first you are getting the desired value that you want to set to TextField.

if the value you getting is correct then set the state

```
  const closeEmail = (email: IEmail) => {
  const test = email.emailAddress;
//add
  console.log("test",test);
//add
  setEmailValue(test);
  setOpenEmail(false);
  return email.emailAddress;
}
```

Adding this setEmailValue(test) will set state,
now you can access by using 'emailValue'

add the following

```
<TextField
value={emailValue}
style={{ width: "95%" }}
onChange={emailOnChange}
label="Email Address"
variant="filled"
 />
```

This is how you can set the email.emailAddress value to TextField

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you want to control the value of your TextInput you should pass **value prop** to your TextInput.

```
<TextField
   style={{ width: "95%" }}
   value={email.emailAddress}
   label="Email Address"
   variant="filled"
   name={email.emailAddress}
   defaultValue={email.emailAddress}
   onChange={emailOnChange}
/>
```

You can have controlled or uncontrolled components:

- A Controlled Component is one that takes its current value through
  props and notifies changes through callbacks like onChange. A parent
  component "controls" it by handling the callback and managing its
  own state and passing the new values as props to the controlled
  component. You could also call this a "dumb component". A
- Uncontrolled Component is one that stores its own state internally,
  and you query the DOM using a ref to find its current value when you
  need it. This is a bit more like traditional HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass value of `textField` like this,

```
 <TextField
    value={email.emailAddress}
    ...
/>
```